# How can I draw an arrow linking two items in a list?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I know you can use the package **tikz** to have braces like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\begin{document}
\MyText[2em]{start1}{end1}{Technological cascade}
\newcommand\MyText[4][0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace},decorate,thick]
( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (#1,1.3ex) $ ) --  
node[anchor=west,xshift=5pt,text width=5cm] {#4} 
( $ (pic cs:#3) + (#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{itemize}
\item Processing \tikzmark{start1}
\item Embedding in paraffin blocks
\item Microtomy
\item Staining
\item Microscopy \tikzmark{end1}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However, I have an arrow back, like negative connection:

**How can you make such arrows in a list?**

[image]

You can also propose other ways to say and visualise the effect what is in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply the same principle, using `\tikzmark` to place some marks and then draw an arrow connecting the marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,decorations.markings}

\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{166,35,41}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{248,219,162}

\NewDocumentCommand\MyArrow{O{0pt}mmmO{out=150,in=210}}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->,thick,line width=4pt,#4]
    ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (-#1,1.3ex) $ ) to[#5]  
    ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (-#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\MyArrow[2em]{start1}{end1}{colorii,line width=6pt}
\MyArrow[1em]{start2}{end1}{colori}[out=120,in=250,looseness=1.2]

\begin{itemize}
\item\tikzmark{end1}Processing 
\item Embedding in paraffin blocks
\item Microtomy
\item\tikzmark{start2}Staining
\item\tikzmark{start1}Microscopy 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax for `\MyArrow` is:

```
\MyArrow[<length>]{<mark1>}{<mark2>}{<options1>}[<options2>]
```

where `<length>` controls the horizontal shifting of the arrow ends (default:`0pt`), `<mark1>` and `<mark2>` are the marks that will be used to draw the arrow, `<options1>` are TikZ options to be passed to the `\draw` command, and `<options2>` are TikZ options to be passes to the `to` path used to draw the arrow (default: `out=150,in=210`).

Another example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,decorations.markings}

\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{166,35,41}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{248,219,162}

\NewDocumentCommand\MyArrow{O{0pt}mmmO{out=150,in=210}}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->,thick,line width=4pt,#4]
    ( $ ({pic cs:#3}|-{pic cs:#2}) + (-#1,1.3ex) $ ) to[#5]  
    ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (-#1,0) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\MyArrow[0.8em]{start1}{end1}{colorii,line width=3pt}[out=90,in=-90]
\MyArrow[1.8em]{start2}{end1}{colori}[out=120,in=250]

\begin{itemize}
\item\tikzmark{end1}Processing 
\item\tikzmark{start1}Embedding in paraffin blocks
\item Microtomy
\item\tikzmark{start2}Staining
\item Microscopy 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a problem that the arrows must be in small spaces like https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-12%20at%2011.59.10.png What is the simplest way to target this challenge?

Comment: @Masi in cases like that, one can change the `out`, `in` keys in the second optional argument. Using a straight arrow, as in the last example of my updated answer, can give a better result here.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! The figure looks now like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-12%20at%2019.42.50.png The right-hand-side arrow is not perfectly in the middle of the two dots. How can you move the arrow little to the left?

Comment: @Masi You're welcome! Change the value used in the first optional argument (instead of `0.8em` use `1em` or `1.2em`or the required length).